# How to send API request to AWS Mturk API (Signature V4) using R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, api

The MturkR package (https://github.com/cloudyr/MTurkR) will stop working on June 1st 2019 as AWS is deprecating the legacy API and this package is only configured for the legacy API.

I imagine many others will need a way to make calls to the MTurk API through R as I don't know of any other R package that can do this.

Can anyone provide some example code of how to make a call to the new mturk API through R? It uses Signature Version 4 which I know can be implemented with the aws.signature package for R but I can't figure out how to generate and send a request to the mturk API. Probably I don't have the request configured correctly, hence an example that works would be fantastic for myself and others. In this example I'm trying to request a GetAssignment operation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetAssignmentOperation.html).

I have tried to use aws.signature package to generate and send a request, but have not succeeded.

```r
library(aws.signature)


hdrs <- list( Host = "mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
             `x-amz-date` = "20110909T233600Z"
                 )

hdrs

r <- canonical_request(verb = "POST",
                  canonical_uri="/",
                  query_args=list(),
                  canonical_headers=hdrs,
                  request_body='
                  { 
                  "AssignmentId": "3ZURAPD288NZQKK965W2FVL02P6F17"
                }')
r
```

This generates the text of a canonical request but I don't know how to send that to the API and I don't know if any more functions are needed to complete the signature.

Response:

> r
>   $`headers`
>   [1] "host;x-amz-date"

$body
[1] "1d67d950ce9a1f712609c9c9d794b210d8c78bc0334e54f0fdcb4fd46d65f3f5"

$canonical
[1] "POST\n/\n\nhost:mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20110909T233600Z\n\nhost;x-amz-date\n1d67d950ce9a1f712609c9c9d794b210d8c78bc0334e54f0fdcb4fd46d65f3f5"

$hash
[1] "16814afb1f9c9c5094a8b3ede035365a687c68c7b6dcbe0f688aaeb8b6656f10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question. Someone published his updated version of MTurkR to Github: https://github.com/cloudyr/pyMTurkR